# Code in Android Studio failed to display Array List

Tags: android

I have been trying to create an output for an array list of API books using JSON object and this array code gives a hint **not a statement**. Below is the block of code in Java using Android Studio

```
Book book = new Book {
  bookJSON.getString(ID),
    volumeInfoJSON.getString(TITLE),
    (volumeInfoJSON.isNull(SUBTITLE)?"":volumeInfoJSON.getString(SUBTITLE)),
    authors, volumeInfoJSON.getString(PUBLISHER), 
    volumeInfoJSON.getString(PUBLISHED_DATE);

    books.add(book);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should change it like this?

```
Book book = new Book {
    bookJSON.getString(ID),
    volumeInfoJSON.getString(TITLE),
    (volumeInfoJSON.isNull(SUBTITLE)?"":volumeInfoJSON.getString(SUBTITLE)),
    authors, volumeInfoJSON.getString(PUBLISHER), 
    volumeInfoJSON.getString(PUBLISHED_DATE);
}
books.add(book);
```

The only difference is I put the `books.add(book)` statement out of `new Book {}` block.